# How does the female Q teleport near the end of Star Trek: Eternal Tide?

Tags: star-trek, books, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-q

Towards the end of the book *Star Trek: Eternal Tide*, the female Q has her powers taken from her, but still manages to teleport herself after screaming really loud.

> Icheb was accustomed to seeing the Q work their particular powers in
> bright flashes of light. This Q threw her head back and uttered a
> bone-shaking cry that immediately forced every head in the room to
> turn toward her. When it had ended, her form slowly began to waver
> before him. The excruciating pain of the effort she was expending was
> clear, until she was gone.

When she teleports next to the male Q, he remarks that she would be in trouble with the Continuum for using that form of transport. Nothing more is elaborated on this.

> “How did you come here?” Q asked of his mother.
>
> She shook her head dismissively. “The power of the Q Continuum is
> great, but it’s not the only source available to us.”
>
> “We’re not permitted,” Q stammered.
>
> “Like that could ever stop your mother,” his father chided him.
> Placing an arm around her and pulling her close, he added, “The
> Continuum will never forgive you for it, though.”
>
> “I don’t care,” she replied.

Does anyone know what type of transport she did? It seemed like the author paid it a lot more attention than if it was just supposed to be a mystery.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's reasonable to assume that she somehow used a small part of the *Omega* Continuum's power. That would be the only source of power that is likely to be forbidden to members of the Q continuum, since the Q exist specifically to counter Omega and using its power would essentially be undoing their work in that respect.

> “It’s Omega?” Chakotay asked.
>
> Eden smiled bitterly. “The particle the Borg thought of as perfection and the Caeliar managed to domesticate as a power source is a pale reflection of true Omega. They were synthetic particles, corrupted by the boronite used to create them. The Omega Continuum is a discrete region underpinning the entire multiverse, composed entirely of pure Omega. It contains the destructive force required to end the multiverse, once it has run its course, and at the same time give rise to the next multiverse. It is an integral part of the eternal cycle of birth, life, and death.”
>
> “Is it anything like the Q Continuum?” Kathryn asked.
>
> Eden nodded. “They exist to balance one another.”
>
> Chakotay shook his head. “How?”
>
> “The Q Continuum contains the ultimate creative power of the multiverse. Omega is the ultimate destructive force,” Eden explained. “Both release their power slowly over vast expanses of time and in precise relation to one another until the multiverse has run its course, a process that normally takes much longer than any of us could imagine.”

Quite how she managed this feat with only a human body at her disposal isn't explained, but this is a Q that managed to use a ship that's only two steps up from the discovery of the wheel to enter the Q Continuum, so she's clearly very handy with primitive technology.

Comment: I appreciate the answer and it seems like that could be the case, however it's stated earlier in the book that the Q continuum isn't aware of the omega continuum in anyway.... I was wondering if it might have showed up in another book involving Q. I haven't read them all so maybe it's touched upon again?

Comment: @user62090 - Q talks about them a little bit, so they obviously have *some* awareness of the particle, at the very least